# Haskell strange `zip` error

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors

I'm trying to zip two `[[Float]]` arrays, and then preform a calculation on each element. The resulting zip-ed array will have type `[([Float], [Float])]`, I think.

But I keep on getting an error where Haskell tells me:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Mod               ( Mod.hs, interpreted )

NN.hs:38:42:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Float]’ with ‘Float’
    Expected type: [Float]
      Actual type: [[Float]]
    In the second argument of ‘zip’, namely ‘bs’
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(zip ws bs)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I can't seem to figure out a MCVE, because this is what if (kinda/sorta) trying to do:

```
feedforward :: ([[Float]], [[Float]]) -> Float -> [Float]
feedforward (ws, bs) a = map (equation a) (zip ws bs)
  where equation a (w, b) = (sum $ zipWith (*) w b) + a
```

But that actually compiles! Whereas my real code looks like this:

```
data NNetwork = NNetwork { nlayers :: Int
                         , sizes   :: [Int]
                         , biases  :: [[Float]]
                         , weights :: [[Float]] }
                deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

toFloat x = fromIntegral x :: Float

sig :: Float -> Float
sig a = 1 / (1 + exp (-a))


feedforward :: NNetwork -> Float -> [Float]
feedforward net a = map (eq22 a) (zip ws bs)
  where bs = biases net
        ws = weights net
        dot a b = sum $ zipWith (*) a b
        rep a b = replicate (length a) b
        eq22 a (w, b) = sig $ (dot w (rep w a)) + b
```

And yet it **doesn't work**!

- Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't given us most of your code (`biases`? `NNetwork`? `sig`?), so we can't help.

Comment: Add more type signatures. For example, if you give a type to `eq22` and the compiler disagrees with that type then you will get a more localized, and typically easier to understand, type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
eq22 :: Float -> ([Float], [Float]) ->  Float
eq22 a (w, b) = sig $ (dot w (rep w a)) + b
```

Except that in this context `b` is a `[Float]` and used as a `Float` (see `+ b`).  Did you mean some sort of function over `b`?

Also, these are not arrays, but lists.